# ExUnit.CaptureIO still waits for input on multiple IO.read calls

Tags: input, elixir, ex-unit

Consider the following minimal [?] example:

```
defmodule Foo do
  def bar() do
    n = IO.read(:line) |> String.trim() |> String.to_integer()
    for _ <- 0..n - 1 do
      IO.read(:line) |> IO.write()
    end
  end
end

import ExUnit.CaptureIO
capture_io("2\nabc\ndef", Foo.bar)
```

I did look into the documentation, and it puts no limitations on `ExUnit.CaptureIO` usage, but the aforelisted code hangs, waiting for the first line of input, as if it hasn't been fed. Have I missed something?

If it matters, I'm using Elixir 1.7.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `capture_io` needs to be a function to run with the capturing enabled. Here, you're passing in the result of running `Foo.bar`. That hangs forever, as it is expecting input from stdio, which never comes. Long story short you need to pass it as a function:

```
capture_io("2\nabc\ndef", &Foo.bar/0)
```

because `Foo.bar` is the same as `Foo.bar()`.